# different versions of php being used

Tags: php, installation, ini

I am trying to install magento and it keeps throwing the error "PHP extension mcrypt must be loaded". When I tried to install mcrypt I got a message that it is already installed.

So I ran `php -v`, `which php` and `php -i | grep mcrypt` in the command line and got back

```
PHP 5.4.23 (cli)....
```

and

```
/usr/local/bin/php
```

and

```
mcrypt
mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value
```

So I added `phpinfo(); die();` to my index.php magento file and that returned

**Version** 5.4.17

**Configuration File (php.ini) Path**   /etc

**Loaded Configuration File**   /etc/php.ini

but no reference to mcrypt

Am I right in reading that as magento is using a different version of php to what the commandline is? and if so how do I resolve this situation?

I am running other installs of Magento and so when I considered trying to delete /etc and letting Magento automatically pick up the correct version, I decided against it as I don't want the other installs to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Echo your `phpinfo()`. Via cmd it's possible to receive other information then needed. You'll see which PHP version is used and where your php.ini is located.

Open php.ini and search for `;php_mcrypt.dll`. Remove the semicolon and restart Apache.

**Edit**: for Linux versions:

- `apt-get install php5-mcrypt`
- `service apache2 restart` - restart Apache

If you get the 'already installed' message you could use:

`apt-get --reinstall install php5-mcrypt`

Make sure that the semicolon is remove in php.ini: `extension=mcrypt.so`

Comment: I have tried to use `apt-get install php5-mcrypt` but I get an error `command not found:`. I have tried to install mcrypt using homebrew but it seems to default to `/usr/local/bin/php` so it tells me mcrypt is already installed

Comment: With which Linux distribution are you working? `apt-get` is for Ubuntu. You could try reinstall `mcrypt`.

Comment: I am using a mac on the Maverick version. My problem is that when I try to install mcrypt it seems to default the `/usr/local/bin/php` which in turn tells me `mcrypt` is already installed

Answer (score 0):

You are right when you say that magento is using different php version (altough only subversion). It is most likely that your cli .ini is different from apache .ini

What you can try is add extension=mcrypt.so to /etc/php.ini and restart apache

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but adding `extension=mcrypt.so` and restarting has not worked. I could not find any other `.so` files so I added it below `;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll`, would location make a difference?